# Bash script to unzip multiple files

Tags: bash, unzip

I have various zip files that contain subfolders and no subfolders. I wish to extract all the zip to its folder. My current script does what I want if it contains subfolders. However, if there are no subfolder, it list them separately in same folder which will be confusing as I need to know what they are.

*Before unzip folder structure*:

JCB-1.zip

```
- JCB  
   - KDY231-8000018  
      -> file1.txt, file2.txt  
   - KGC30-0152537  
      -> file1.txt, file2.txt  
   - S330V-0034006  
      -> file1.txt, file2.txt
```

XZC605-0002319.zip

```
   - file_1.txt ,file_2.txt, file_3.txt
```

ZNE10-7845839.zip

```
- ZNE10-7845839  
  -> file1.txt, file2.txt
```

*After unzip folder structure*:

```
- KDY231-8000018  
- KGC30-0152537  
- S330V-0034006  
- file_1.txt  
- file_2.txt  
- file_3.txt
```

Current Script

```
#!/bin/bash

ZIPDIR=/mnt/www/log/_tmp
TMP=/tmp/zipfiles

cd $ZIPDIR
rm tmp/zipfiles 2>/dev/null

ls -l *.zip
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo ".zip file found"

ls -1 $ZIPDIR/*.zip > $TMP

for i in `cat $TMP`
do
  unzip -o $i && rm $i
done
fi;

# Removing top level folder
mv $ZIPDIR/JCB/* . && rm -R JCB

if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
  echo "NOT found"
fi;
```

My thinking is that the zip that doesn't have subfolders, I will need to create them from fileName.zip and not from file_1.txt as the name doesn't make sense. Thus, the final result will be this structure after unzipping.

*Final Expecting unzip folder structure*:

```
- KDY231-8000018  
- KGC30-0152537  
- S330V-0034006  
- XZC605-0002319
```

Updated:
The code provide by @confetti works. Thanks. There is another zip file structure I forgot to mention and I have included above. Here is the final code with my edits. It may not be an efficient code, but it does seem to work for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

zipdir=/mnt/www/log/_tmp
cd $zipdir

for i in *.zip; do
    folder=${i::-4}
        mkdir -p  $folder
    unzip -o $i -d $folder && rm $i
    subdirs=$(find $folder -type d | wc -l)
    if [[ $subdirs -eq 2 ]]; then
        mv ./$folder/* ./
        rm -r $folder
    else if [[ $subdirs -gt 1 ]]; then
        mv ./$folder/*/* ./
        rm -r $folder
    fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: [*Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
ZIPDIR=/mnt/www/log/_tmp
TMP=/tmp/zipfiles
cd "$ZIPDIR"
rm tmp/zipfiles 2>/dev/null

for i in ./*.zip; do
    folder=${i::-4}
    mkdir "$folder"
    unzip -o "$i" -d "$folder" && rm "$i"
    subdirs=$(find "$folder" -type d -printf ".\n" | wc -l)
    if [[ $subdirs -gt 1 ]]; then
        mv ./$folder/*/* ./
        rm -r "$folder"
    fi
done
```

Tested it with files similar to your shown structure and works perfectly for me.

Comment: I am getting errors with different zip files and it's saving 2 folders deep for some.

**JCB-6.zip <-- Has subfolder**
`./batchUnzip.sh: line 13: [[: JCB-6 
JCB-6/JCB
JCB-6/JCB/NCP51-0284052: syntax error in expression (error token is "JCB-6/JCB
JCB-6/JCB/NCP51-0284052")`

**XZC605-0002319.zip <-- No subfolder**
`./batchUnzip.sh: line 13: [[: XZC605-0002319: value too great for base (error token is "0002319")`

Comment: My fault. I forgot the `| wc -l` behind the find command to get the actual _number_ of sub-directories. I've edited my answer. It was basically comparing a string list of sub-directories to a number before. Eops.

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time helping out. Did you get a chance to test the code? While the error is gone, it's giving me a weird results.

Comment: Check it out now. I've missed the `./$folder/*` in the `mv` command at the bottom. Essentially trying to move a folder into itself, eops. I've tried the current code and it works for me.